# How to add Condition for apply Promotion rules while create order Programmatically in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, promotions, rules

**I want to add a condition (whether to apply the promotion rule or not as per the configuration settings) before the Promotion rule applied while create order Programmatically**. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: what type of condition?? explain briefly

Comment: @Gopal I have updated my question.